# Adding custom meta fields to pryocms blog posts

Tags: pyrocms

I'm relatively new to PyroCMS, but enjoying it as a nice change from Wordpress!

One thing I would like to resolve is how to add custom meta tags to individual blog posts. I would see this working as follows:

- An additional tab would be displayed on the blog post edit page
- Text boxes would allow the meta content (a few set tags) to be typed in and saved to the database
- When the blog post is viewed the post specific meta would be retrieved and inserted into the meta head tags.

From my initial reading this sounds like a job for streams and a module.  Am I on the right track or is there a better approach? Can anybody point me in the right direction for some reading to get me started?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm starting to think there is no 'easy' solution so I think I'm going to extend the blog module...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of further research, this is not currently possible in v2.1 of PyroCMS without rewriting the blog module.

> As for adding custom fields, yep that is one rigid problem we have right now. If you want to add fields you need to hack it, which as long as you are using Git for your upgrades won't be a huge issue.

From version 2.2 this should be possible using streams

> PyroCMS v2.2 will be moving Pages and Blogs backend to use Streams, meaning custom fields can be added and deleted, just like we did with the Profile fields. For now, no options other than either A) hack it or B) create your own custom module (call it something other than blog) and modify it.

[SOURCE - Phil Sturgeon](https://www.pyrocms.com/forums/topics/view/13813#16617)